# Different result of aes encryption c++ and php

Tags: php, c++, encryption, aes

I'm going to implement AES encryption between CPP and PHP. But the result of each of them is different with each other and therefore they cannot decode each other. I use the OpenSsl library for encryption.

my php code:

```
        $key = '1234567890123456';
        $iv = '1234567890123456';

        $enc = openssl_encrypt("hello wolrd", 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($enc, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

and result: ��.�+'W�x�@�

my cpp code:

```
int aes_encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int aes_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}


    /* A 256 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char*)"1234567890123456";

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char*)"1234567890123456";

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char*)"hello wolrd";

    /* Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
    * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, dependant on the
    * algorithm and mode
    */
    unsigned char ciphertext[256];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[256];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    printf("Plaintext is:\n%s\n", plaintext);

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = aes_encrypt(plaintext, strlen((const char*)plaintext), key, iv,
                             ciphertext);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is %d bytes long:\n", ciphertext_len);
    BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char*)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = aes_decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';
```

and result: �'^{�'ی�u�E��@@�s

what is the problem?

Comment: Seems you are having trouble counting to 32.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Can you explain more?